# Inject `@PathVariable` into a request scoped bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scope, request

I want to propagate some path variables as a part of request scoped bean.
I want this bean to be immutable, and I don't want to parse the path manually and depend on `javax.servlet` stuff

Now I see the solution with setting up `Provider<MyPathVariables>` in the `@ControllerAdvice`
But I don't like making `MyPathVariables` mutable.

Another option is injecting `HttpServletRequest` into my bean constructor and manually parsing the path, and I also don't like this double working, and especially I don't like dependency to `javax.servlet` in my beautiful spring app.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 2):

Spring creates a map attribute containing the path parameters keyed by name on the request. The name of the attribute is stored in this constant:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping#URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE
```

You can get it using the following:

```
Map<String, String> getPathParameters(HttpServletRequest request){
    return (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)
}
```